# Publish on a Topic for a certain time

Tags: ros, linear-velocity, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know if it is possible to publish on a topic for a certain time (fixed before publishing).

For example, I want to publish a linear velocity (geometry_msgs/Twist Message)  for 3 seconds and then robot stops.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274345/publish-on-a-topic-for-a-certain-time/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2017-10-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should create your own node that will do this. You can do this in c++ or python.

Follow the **Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber** tutorial that teaches you how to make a publisher and subscriber node. You are only concerned with making a publisher node, but if you haven't done these tutorials, you should.

Here's the c++ version: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

Here's the python version: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

Here is an example with UNTESTED CODE of how you would do this in c++:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  
  // Advertize the publisher on the topic you like
  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("my_topic_name", 1000);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    /**
     * This is a message object. You stuff it with data, and then publish it.
     */
    geometry_msgs::Twist myTwistMsg

    // Here you build your twist message
    myTwistMsg.linear.x = 1;
    myTwistMsg.linear.y = 2;
    myTwistMsg.linear.z = 3;
    
    ros::Time beginTime = ros::Time::now();
    ros::Duration secondsIWantToSendMessagesFor = ros::Duration(3); 
    ros::Time endTime = beginTime + secondsIWantToSendMessagesFor;
    while(ros::Time::now() < endTime )
    {
        pub.publish(msg);
        
        // Time between messages, so you don't blast out an thousands of 
        // messages in your 3 secondperiod
        ros::Duration(0.1).sleep();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) with karma: 258 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thanks a lot for your help!

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-04**:
Thank you so much bro!